# My visibility condition in SSRS caused "[BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments." error

Tags: reporting-services, expression, server-side-rendering, visibility, iif

I am using the following expression for a row visibility rule:

```sql
=IIF(Sum(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) > 0 
AND (Count(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) < Parameters!Consecutive.Value)), true, false)
```

When I try saving the report I get the following error message:

> "The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments."

I think I only have three arguments, as I should.  What am I doing wrong?

I have also attempted to replace the `IIF` with something like this:

```sql
=IIF(Sum(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) > 0, true, false) 
AND IIF((Count(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) < Parameters!Consecutive.Value), true, false)
```

I got the same error.

Comment: I have now tried 

=IIF(Sum(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) > 0 AND Count(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) < Parameters!Consecutive.Value, true, false)

It seems to have gotten rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extra closing parethesis at the end of the parameter value that causing the IIF to close with only one argument.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) > 0 
AND (Count(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) < Parameters!Consecutive.Value)), true, false)
```

Your working answer removed the opening parenthesis before the count and the TWO after the parameter.

Removing just one would have worked. This is why I try to use as few parenthesis as possible, but as many as needed.

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) > 0 
AND (Count(Fields!bt_actual_usage.Value) < Parameters!Consecutive.Value), true, false)
```